# Unable to go to next page using the onChange function in MaterialTable

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, material-table

I'm trying to change the page in MaterialTable but am unable to do so. Although, the page size functionality is working but the page change functionality isn't.

Here is my state:

```
constructor(props) {
    super(props)
    this.state = {
        status: false,
        message: "",
        page: 0,
        pageSize: 5,
    }
}
```

And inside MaterialTable, I have this:

```
<MaterialTable
                            title=""
                            page={this.state.page}
                            totalCount={this.props.operations.ids ? this.props.operations.ids.length : 0}
                            columns={[
                                {
                                    title: 'Sr No.', field: 'serialNumber', render: rowData => {
                                        return _.findIndex(renderingData, { "id": rowData.id }) + 1
                                    }
                                },
                                { title: 'Time Stamp', field: 'date', render: rowData => { return moment(rowData.date).format("YYYY/MM/DD hh:mm a") } },
                                { title: 'Details', field: 'name' },
                                {
                                    title: 'View Details', field: 'viewDetails', render: rowData => {
                                        return <Button
                                            variant="contained"
                                            color={"primary"}
                                            onClick={() => this.props.setTab(rowData)}
                                        >View</Button>
                                    }
                                },
                            ]}
                            onChangePage={(page, pageSize) => {
                                this.setState({ ...this.state, page, pageSize})
                            }}
data={renderingData}
/>
```

Let me know if any modification is required for this. I still haven't been able to solve the problem.

Comment: it is also depended how much data has table , if table has sufficient data , next button will be enabled else it will disable

Comment: There are 6 elements in the table. Initially it shows 5 rows but when I click on next, it should show the 6th row on a new page.

Comment: Yes, it's right and it's expected behaviour, because your table pageSize is 5 so it  shows only 5 elements in the table and 6th element will appear in next page

Comment: Yes, that's expected. But the problem is, there is no 6th element on the next page. When I click next, it just shows the same 5 elements that were showing previously. Ideally, it should show the 6th element on the next page and it should be the only row.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, so the problem was that the data that goes into Material Table was the same even after clicking the Next page button. I went around it by adding this in the data. The rest of the code is the same.

```
data={renderingData.slice(this.state.page*this.state.pageSize, this.state.page*this.state.pageSize + this.state.pageSize)}
```

This code makes sure that new data is present when you click on next page.

Answer (score 0):

clicking on next button , you also need to increase the page number

`onChangePage={(event,page ) => { this.setState({ ...this.state, page}) }}`

also change
`function handleChangeRowsPerPage(event) { setRowsPerPage(+event.target.value); }`

Comment: That's giving an error. Apparently, we can't just write page+1 directly. I also tried page: page+1 which doesn't give any error but even that's not working.

Comment: what error it's throwing also it would be helpful if you can replicate in codepen or codesandbox

Comment: I'm not sure how to replicate the whole thing in CodePen and it's also a company project. I tried using page: page+1 and although it doesn't give any error, it still doesn't solve the problem.

Comment: Tried the new code where event was used as the 1st argument, but it's not showing any difference. Also the event word was faded (VS fades out variables/functions that are not called anywhere) in Visual Studio which means that maybe nothing triggered it?

Comment: which version of material-Ui are you using ?

Comment: The material table is 1.68.1

Comment: The others:   "@material-ui/core": "^4.11.0",
    "@material-ui/icons": "^4.9.1",
    "@material-ui/lab": "^4.0.0-alpha.49",
    "@material-ui/pickers": "^3.2.10",

Comment: please try to match your code with this documentation
https://material-ui.com/components/tables/#table

Comment: It doesn't use MaterialTable component which I used but instead uses the Table and TablePagination component which means I have to modify a lot of my existing code but I can look into it.

Comment: Still haven't been able to solve the issue. Have updated my whole code. You can see it.